# What does ㊙︎DVD mean?

Tags: slang, abbreviations, symbols

everyone,

Ran across this line ㊙︎DVD, with the 秘 encircled. Do any of you know what this might mean?

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210118/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common abbreviation style to suggest a certain phrase by enclosing a single kanji in the word. Some frequently used symbols are now officially available on the computer (see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_CJK_Letters_and_Months), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Ideographic_Supplement)) due to typographical needs.

In this case,

> ㊙︎ = 秘密【ひみつ】 = "secret, confidential, classified" (often in ads or catch lines)

It can be read aloud [丸秘【まるひ】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210118/meaning/m0u/) "circle(d) ひ". The formal typographical name is 丸囲み【まるかこみ】秘. This character can also be used as an emoji (㊙️).

Others include:

- ㊐㊊㊋㊌㊍㊎㊏: days of week (Sun, Mon, ... Sat)
- ㊤㊥㊦: part I, II and III of trilogy works

There are unencoded but famous ones including マル暴, which is originally a police jargon associated with 暴力団【ぼうりょくだん】 or yakuza.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I supposed that was it, but I wasn't sure

Answer (score 0):

The ㊙︎DVD actually means **Secret DVD** or **confidential DVD**.

Comment: What new value does your answer bring in addition to the [previously posted one](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43646/11104)?